# Bind selected radio button value in KnockOut - ASP.net project

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I'm new to KnockOut and I just wanted to bind selected radio button value to td. For my knowledge I didn't do any mistake but my following code doesn't work anymore. Please help me to solve this minor mistake.
Other code parts are working fine in the same page, So nothing wrong other than this code part.

```
<td data-bind="text: Sex"></td>
<td>
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonMale" value="Male" GroupName="RadioGroup1" data-bind="checked: Sex" runat="server" Text="Male"/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonFemale" value="Female" GroupName="RadioGroup1" data-bind="checked: Sex" runat="server" Text="Female"/>
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var ViewModel =  {
            Sex : ko.observable("Male"),
        };
        ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
 </script>
```

Comment: The code looks correct. Are there any errors in the javascript console? When I just did the client side code without asp.net it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/so81Lpv4/

Comment: What do the `<input>` tags that are generated for the `<asp:RadioButton>` controls look like?  i.e. Does everything look right if you view source in the browser?

Comment: Generated HTML code for Radio button: <span data-bind="checked: Sex"><input id="RadioButtonMale" type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Male" /><label for="RadioButtonMale">Male</label></span>
                    <span data-bind="checked: Sex"><input id="RadioButtonFemale" type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Female" /><label for="RadioButtonFemale">Female</label></span>

Comment: @WayneEllery No errors, But got a warning 'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead.

Comment: In the generated code you can see that the `data-bind` is generated on the `span` instead of the `input`. With this setup the checked binding won't work. Instead of the `<asp:RadioButton` just write out the `input` by hand `<span><input id="RadioButtonFemale" type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Female" data-bind="checked: Sex" /><label for="RadioButtonFemale">Female</label></span> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html that asp .net is generating is incorrect. It needs to have data-bind="checked: Sex" on the input instead of the span. Instead of using <`asp:RadioButton` do the following:

```
<input type="radio" ID="RadioButtonMale" value="Male" Name="RadioGroup1" data-bind="checked: Sex" runat="server"><label for="RadioButtonMale">Male</label>
<input type="radio" ID="RadioButtonFemale" value="Female" Name="RadioGroup1" data-bind="checked: Sex" runat="server" Text="Male"><label for="RadioButtonFemale">Female</label>
```

Comment: Is that mean we can't use asp.net controls against KnockOut every time?

Comment: You can use most controls but not RadioButton. Normally if you are using knockout it's best to not use any server controls and just use html, javascript and ajax.